# Django 1.7 and PSQL: on_delete=models.SET_NULL not work

Tags: python, django, django-models

My models.py:

```
class MyFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="myfiles", max_length=500, storage=OverwriteStorage())
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank=True, null=True)
    date_expired = models.DateTimeField(default=default_time, blank=True, null=True)
    expires = models.BooleanField(default=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('myfile:myfile-new', )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.file.name
        super(MyFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file.delete(False)
        super(MyFile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        managed = True

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=MyFile)
def remove_file(**kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    instance.file.delete(save=False)


class Operation(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    myfile = models.ForeignKey(MyFile, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_data(self):
        return json.loads(self.data)

    class Meta:
        managed = True

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    subscribe = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Profile of user: %s' % (self.user.username)

    class Meta:
        managed = True

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    from django.conf import settings
    subscribe = False 
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance, subscribe=subscribe)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

But, if User deleted, all related myfiles still deleted.

Any idea? Thanks

**UPDATE**

Database is postgres9.3.5, and I used \d+ to check the information of tables before and after migration, **NO difference**. wired.

```
# \d+ ui.myproject_myfile;
                                                            Table "ui.myproject_myfile"
    Column    |           Type           |                            Modifiers                             | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id           | integer                  | not null default nextval('ui.myproject_myfile_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 file         | character varying(500)   | not null                                                         | extended |              | 
 slug         | character varying(500)   | not null                                                         | extended |              | 
 user_id      | integer                  |                                                                  | plain    |              | 
 date_created | timestamp with time zone |                                                                  | plain    |              | 
 date_expired | timestamp with time zone |                                                                  | plain    |              | 
 expires      | boolean                  | not null                                                         | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "myproject_myfile_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "myproject_myfile_2dbcba41" btree (slug)
    "myproject_myfile_e8701ad4" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "myproject_myfile_user_id_a422765c7101118_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES ui.auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "ui.myproject_operation" CONSTRAINT "myproject_ope_myfile_id_3f071e8e8361943b_fk_myproject_myfile_id" FOREIGN KEY (myfile_id) REFERENCES ui.myproject_myfile(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Has OIDs: no
```

**UPDATE**

```
#ALTER TABLE ui.myproject_myfile ADD CONSTRAINT user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

**Then, I found the following added to the descriptions of my table. But still not work. If user deleted, all myfiles deleted, too.**
"user_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES ui.auth_user(id) ON DELETE SET NULL

**UPDATE**

I am thinking about whether to delete this post. Problem solved after VM rebooted. NO idea why. But thank all of you.

Comment: Could it be that the relations are deleted, and you think it's the related myfiles?

Comment: @ElwinArens NO, if user deleted, all files deleted too.

Comment: To ask a stupid question: did you remember to do the makemigrations and migrate after you changed the foreign key?

Comment: @e4c5, yes, But I used \d+ to check the information of tables before and after migration, no difference. wired.

Comment: show the latest migration number in your app/migrations folder and also the number in django_migrations table

Comment: @e4c5 All migrations done. but descriptions of my table not changed. please see my update. Thanks

Comment: Well your table has been updated, and that definitely will result in the field being set to null. Are you quite sure that you don't have a post save signal or a trigger that messes things up

Comment: what is your User model django.contrib.auth.models.User?

Comment: @e4c5 yes, you are right. my User Model is django.contrib.auth.models.User

Comment: well then, all I can say is that you have a trigger or signal somewhere other than the models.py fil

Comment: @e4c5 you mean that User sends some post_save signal? and this signal got messed up?

Comment: You probably have one some where.

Comment: Sorry post_delete or pre_delete more likely

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `on_delete` results in all related objects being deleted; in this case, the related object is MyFile.

If you're trying to preserve the MyFile object, maybe consider adding a default via `on_delete=SET_DEFAULT` or using a callable passed to `on_default=SET(callable)`

Comment: Maybe try making the User model generic and setting the field as a GenericForeignKey.

What exactly is the functionality you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, how to make the User model generic and setting the field as a GenericForeignKey. User model is the django.contrib.auth.User.

Comment: I will try later, But I also try to understand why my codes not work. It should be very easy and straightforward.

Comment: If a MyFile should have a User, but MyFile objects should be preserved when the User is deleted, then I would think that there should be an "Intermediary Table" which has a link from a User object and a link to a MyFile object. That way, you can delete the user and that intermediary table connecting the two, while still preserving the MyFile. This is what Django's ContentTypes framework tries to solve.